# Upper bounding a function of incomplete gamma function

Tags: integration, special-functions, gamma-function, upper-lower-bounds, chi-squared

I have the following function

$$
-\int_A^{\infty} \left(mRr - mR^2/2\right){r^{p-1}} \exp\left( -\frac{\lambda r^2}{2}\right) dr
$$
where $m, R, A, \lambda > 0$. I am trying to find an upper bound on it. There might be two ways to do it, first is by assuming it difference of moment function of chi-squared distribution, another one is by using the below inequality for incomplete gamma function-
Let $B > 1$, and $q \geq \frac{p+1}{2}$. Then, for all $x \geq \frac{B}{B-1}(q-1)$.
\begin{align*}
    \int_{x}^{+\infty}y^{q-1}\exp(-y)dy \leq Bx^{q-1}\exp(-x).
\end{align*}
The above function will help with the positive part but I don't know any good lower bound on the incomplete gamma function. I am not sure how to work around the differences, should I consider them separately?

Comment: Might also want to check out nakagami distribution if you're considering a probabilistic approach.

Comment: Is there any relationship between $A$ and $R$? Because the integrand is positive for $r>R/2$. Thus, if $A<R/2$ you won't need to split the integral into positive and negative components.

Comment: Yes, $A > R$ is the relation